# Chrome closing by itself and sometimes not starting at all.

Tags: google-chrome

Sometimes it can kind of starts, but as soon as I type ANYTHING into the URL bar, the window closes, no crash, no errors that I know of, it simply closes. Other times it doesn't even open. I really have no idea what could be going on, and I'm sorry I can't provide more help, but I really want to get Chrome back, and Firefox makes me want to tear my hair out with the way it renders some pages and how it operates.

Comment: If you run it from the Terminal, is there any output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Chromium from the Software Center and it should work fine. If you installed chrome from the SC, download the deb from the install site. Make sure it is 32 bit or 64 bit just like your system.

Comment: If you also install the Pepper Flash Player from the Optional add-ons section of the Chromium Web Browser screen in the Ubuntu Software Center, you'll also get the same updated version of Flash Player that Google Chrome uses.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the root cause was that there was absolutely no space on the root drive, so chrome was crashing because it could not write to its cache, and that was why some other programs started acting funny, I cleared out some old files on that drive and the issue resolved itself, sorry for the noob mistake...

Comment: Oh, okay, I didn't know it would do that. Well, you fixed it! Happy Chroming!